# Use Google Drive API from Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-developers-console

I want to extend a project in a way that it can save files to Google Drive. To learn how this works I tried the Quick Start Example from the docs: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js

Following the example I noticed that the example is creating an *API key* in the developer console. Following the same steps only returns a *Client secret*. I suspected this to be a naming problem and hoped that the two are the same.

Unfortunately, the example code does not work but loggs the following error:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"keyInvalid","message":"Bad Request"}],"code":400,"message":"Bad Request"}}
```

In the request to:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest?pp=0&fields=kind%2Cname%2Cversion%2CrootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods%2CbatchPath%2Cid&key=[[my key]]
```

I checked that the right secret appears in the request url. Setting `var API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';` to an empty string is a workaround.

How can I debug this further? where do i get the right api key?

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: @LeonardoRick please check my answer, if it is not too late

Answer (score 2):

I run into this error recently. It is certain that Google Documentation is usually quite good, but in this case, the Google Drive API (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js) it wasn't that clear. For this API in particular, you will require two credentials.

Under your project credentials section, you must create an `OAuth 2.0` client for a web application and a `API Key`.

*(Sorry for the Spanish in the screenshots)*

Regarding the `OAuth 2.0` client, **not that I have restricted it to `http://localhost`**
[image: OAuth 2.0 configuration Google Drive API]

Concerning the `API Key`, **note that I have restricted it to my Google Drive API**
[image: API Key configuration Google Drive API]

Then, in the `index.html` provided by the documentation, you can set your `CLIENT_ID` to the one obtained in the `OAuth 2.0` client generation, and the `API_KEY` to the the one generated in the `API Key` process.

Answer (score 0):

> {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"keyInvalid","message":"Bad Request"}],"code":400,"message":"Bad Request"}}

Means that the request you have made has not been properly authenticated.

API key is for accessing public data.  Oauth2 client id and secret will be used to access private user data which file.list is.  So i dont think this is a naming problem.  Your code should be popping up requesting access of the user.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not request access. The code fails before the popup is loaded. I followed the quick start exactly and double checked.